# Let etckeeper monitor /var/spool/cron too

Tags: cron, etckeeper

`etckeeper` should log all config changes on a system. But there is one important setting that is outside of /etc/:

`crontab -e` edits a file inside: `/var/spool/cron/` so there are important config files on the server.

How do I include those files to the git repository of `etckeeper`?

Comment: https://etckeeper.branchable.com/ seems to be the current code

Comment: You could try this: https://serverfault.com/questions/211425/can-etckeeper-be-used-to-track-config-files-outside-of-etc

Answer (score 1):

The `/var/spool/cron` directory contains user's *personal* crontabs.  This data is very different in nature from the system-wide configuration files in `/etc`.  To allow `etckeeper` to handle these would be like monitoring all user's personal `.bashrc` files and pushing changes to a VCS, which seems rather intrusive.

The system's crontab files are all stored under `/etc` so these would be handled by `etckeeper` by default.